# choosing Firegroups in World of Warplanes

Tags: world-of-warplanes

In World of Warplanes you can choose up to 3 firegroups by going to options and binding them to keys.

I would like to be able to set a certain group to RMB. That certain group being my highest caliber guns.

Is there any detrmining factors on what the firing groups are?
for example, is firing group 1 *always* your hub mounted gun while 2 is *always* wing?

Comment: It seems that lower group numbers corresponds to higher caliber guns and vise versa.